# WebStorm node.js script: 'process' Variable might not have been initialized

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I'm trying to migrate a nodejs script previously maintained on [codeanywhere](https://www.codeanywhere.com) to JetBrains WebStorm 2016.2.3 (Build #WS-162.1812.21, built on September 4, 2016).

I've cloned the git repository into a folder and initiated a WebStorm project there.  I also enabled the Node.js Core Library in `Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM` and `Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript -> Libraries`

I also set up some environment variables with WebStorm's UI in my run configuration.

However, I cannot load data from these environment variables, as process is undefined:

[image: Variable might not have been initialized]

I figured it must be an issue with WebStorm's understanding of the code, as the same code works on codeanywhere...  But running it yields the following:

[image]

So apparently process is not defined when executing node through WebStorm?

If I set a breakpoint on the first line and check the variables, there is a local variable called `process` which is undefined, and a global variable of the same name which is properly defined and contains `process.env.TOKEN`.  I never defined such a local variable later in the code, so I'm not sure where it is coming from, but it seems to be getting in the way.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you setup the env variable into the webstorm terminal ?

Comment: Yes.  But notice process is undefined, not the TOKEN

Comment: Will the script run correctly from console (outside WebStorm)? Just a wild guess: please check that all letters in "process" word are English.

Comment: @Sergey.Simonchik Hmm, the script doesn't work from the node console either.  Even though it did on codeanywhere.  It seems to need `global.process.env.TOKEN`.  Maybe that means there's a problem with the node installation or something?  (Since it does work with global, I think the language issue is not the case.)

Comment: I would hazard a guess that something is wrong with the install, as I'm using a similar process, in WebStorm with no problem with the `process` property.  What version of node do you have installed?

Comment: @DaveV `v6.7.0`